# Android viewpager2 inside swipe refresh layout

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

My Fragment code

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        boardViewPagerAdapter.setOnRefreshing { boardId ->
            viewModel.getBoard(boardId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { resource ->
                when (resource) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        val list = boardViewPagerAdapter.list.currentList.toMutableList()
                        val pos = list.indexOfFirst { it.id == boardId }
                        list[pos] = resource.data!!
                        boardViewPagerAdapter.list.submitList(list)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BoardViewPagerAdapter ( I'm using viewpager2 with RecyclerView.Adapter )

```kotlin
inner class BoardHolder(private val binding: CommunityBoardLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(boardItem: CommunityBoard) {
            binding.board = boardItem
            val postAdapter = PostAdapter();
            binding.boardRecycler.adapter = postAdapter.apply { list.submitList(boardItem.posts) }
            binding.swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
                onRef?.let {
                    it.invoke(boardItem.id)
                    binding.swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var onRef: ((boardType: Int) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnRefreshing(callback: (boardType: Int) -> Unit) {
        onRef = callback
    }
```

Community Board layout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="board"
            type="com.danny.domain.models.CommunityBoard" />
    </data>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_gray">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/board_recycler"
            items="@{board.posts}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/board_item_layout" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</layout>
```

I want to get data from MyFragment but refresh is called from boardHolder and it make post Adapter
What should i do.. Any idea for me??
or.. how to make refresh icon wait for data..